# FileZilla: Copy from local computer into multiple folders on server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm using a piece of hardware that has an internal FTP server. On that server are ten folders. I want to know if there is any way, using FileZilla, to copy the contents of a folder on my computer, into each of the ten folders on the FTP server.

If not, is there another piece of software that does this, without development. If not, I'll have to make something myself in Python or LabVIEW.

Please see link below for illustration of these folders.

https://www.segger.com/products/production/flasher/models/gang-programmer-flasher-ate/#configuring-flasher-ate-via-ftp

Comment: If you mapped the folder on the FTP server to a local folder you could write a batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which OS are you using Filezilla? You can use e.g. the built-in [Windows FTP-Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp) on the command line for your uploads, so they can be automated easily.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 64-bit. Thank you for the link and the tip. I think this is the path I will pursue.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command line ftp client has a `-s <filename>` option. which lists what commands to run.

It would look something like this:

```
open ftp.example.com
cd remote_folder1
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder2
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder3
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder4
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder5
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder6
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder7
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder8
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder9
mput Source_dir
cd remote_folder10
mput Source_dir
```